# How to change quaternion to rotation matrix in world coordinate

Tags: rotation, transform, pcl

I am trying to transform point cloud for register.
[image]
I have got quaternion, but when I do the transformation using point cloud library. It seem to transform point cloud in local coordinate instead of world coordinate. So, it can't do the register. I want to know the formula of Quaternion convert to rotation matrix
https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/matrix_transform.html#

Here is my transformation code

```
float qw, qx, qy, qz, tx, ty, tz;
    qw = kinectmatrix4f[num][0];
    qx = kinectmatrix4f[num][1];
    qy = kinectmatrix4f[num][2];
    qz = kinectmatrix4f[num][3];
    tx= kinectmatrix4f[num][4];
    ty = kinectmatrix4f[num][5];
    tz = kinectmatrix4f[num][6];
    //qx = -qx;
    qy = -qy;
    
    //init transformation matrix
    Eigen::Matrix4f transform_matrix = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
    transform_matrix <<
        1 - 2 * pow(qy, 2) - 2 * pow(qz, 2), 2 * qx*qy - 2 * qz*qw, 2 * qx*qz + 2 * qy*qw, 0,
        2 * qx*qy + 2 * qz*qw, 1 - 2 * pow(qx, 2) - 2 * pow(qz, 2), 2 * qy*qz - 2 * qx*qw, 0,
        2 * qx*qz - 2 * qy*qw, 2 * qy*qz + 2 * qx*qw, 1 - 2 * pow(qx, 2) - 2 * pow(qy, 2), 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1;

    printf("Transforming point cloud %i in rough\n", num);
    std::cout << transform_matrix << std::endl;

    pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_input, *cloud_input, transform_matrix);
```

However, I try transformation in **unity** by this code. It seems to change rotation well.

```
Quaternion rot=new Quaternion(0.4f,0.5f,0.9f,1);
transform.rotation=rot;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. But If you are using Eigen here.
You can simply convert quaternion rotation to rotation matrix using Eigen. `Quaternionf.toRotationMatrix()`

```cpp
  Eigen::Quaternionf quat(qw, qx, qy, qz);
  //init transformation matrix
  Eigen::Matrix4f transform_matrix = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
  // convert Quaternion to rotation matrix
  Matrix3f rot_mat = quat.toRotationMatrix();
  // assign the rotation part of transform matrix
  transform_matrix.block(0, 0, 3, 3) = rot_mat;

  // you should create another point cloud to acquire your result
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr transformed_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZ>)
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr transformed_cloud2(new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZ>)

  // do transform
  pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_input, *transformed_cloud, transform_matrix);
  // if above transformed_cloud is not what you expected, try inverse the transform matrix to check if your rotation is "back-ward"
  pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_input, *transformed_cloud2, transform_matrix.inverse());
```